# Enviar e receber SMS vindo de um GPS

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso enviar um `SMS` para um `chip do GPS` e ele me retornará uma coordenada. Como faço para mandar e receber esse `SMS`?

Poderiam colocar exemplos de links e serviços baseados em `HTML` e `JavaScript` para este envio?

Comment: ok Samuel, a sua pergunta esta beeeemm vaga, quer enviar sms no javascript, o javascript por si só não vai fazer isso, você esta usando algum serviço da web, tem um servidor que faz esse sms e quer disparar ele via javascript, explica isso melhor.

Comment: Na real eu não tenho ideia de como faço para mandar o sms e receber ele, se puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Bom já que não faz ideia de onde começar, vou dar uma sugestão:
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45351?hl=pt-BR

Com isso você não precisa programar nenhuma linha de código fonte, bastar ir lá na agenda do google e configurar o envio de sms, a mensagem data/hora para disparar o evento e boa, agora fica a seu critério fazer ou não um sistema que use a API do google calendar para automatizar o processo.